# Supported TLS Cipher suites on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform

I'm checking which TLS cipher suites are supported on Google Cloud Platform. In case of AWS, there are [some supported TLS cipher suites to use their service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-security-identity.html). But, Google Cloud Platform just describes which TLS version is supported. Can I get which cipher suite is mandatory to access Google Cloud Platform by non-Google end users?

For example, web server (or file server) is working on Google Cloud Platform, end user will send and receive encrypted data over TLS. During TLS, which cipher suite should be added?

Answer (score 0):

This has recently become configurable using [SSL Policies](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/ssl-policies).